# Definition of a closed subset of $\mathbb R$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A=\{x\in \mathbb R \mid 0\leq x\}$. Prove that $C$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$.

As far as I understand a closed set/subset is a set that for all sequences within it are bounded and the bound is also an element of the set.

Is this a correct definition? And if so how could it be closed if its elements are not even sequences but an elements of $\mathbb R$? Are the sequences composed from these elements?

What would be a good approach for this question?

Comment: This isn't a correct definition. A correct one is "if a sequence of elements of $C$ converges, then its limit is in $C$". Closed sets need not be bounded.

Comment: @Wojowu The given definition does not require that $C$ be bounded

Comment: @AlexG. Boundedness follows from "all sequences within it are bounded".

Comment: @AlexG. It does. If $A$ would not be bounded, it would contain an unbounded sequence.

Comment: @Wojowu I believe that OP is saying/meant to say that "for all bounded sequences in $C$, the bounds are also in $C$." If that is not what OP meant, they should clarify; the wording is a bit ambiguous

Comment: I'm not sure what a "bound" is when you say "the bound is in the set".  That sounds like you mean limit points.  But in any case when giving a proper definition one needs properly defined terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be three common equivalent definitions.  There is no requirement that the closed set be bounded (as your set $A=\{x\in \mathbb R \mid 0\leq x\}$ is not).

A subset, $A \subseteq X$ of a universal set $X$ is closed if:

i) every limit point (if any) of the set is a member of the set.

A limit point is a point, $x$, so that for every real number $\delta > 0$ then every set $N_{\delta}(x) = \{y \in X| d(x,y) < \delta \}$ will contain a point of $A$ that is distinct from $x$.

This assumes X is a metric space as $\mathbb R$ is.

If $A$ has no limit points (as the empty set, a set of singletons, or the set of integers don't) then $A$ is vacuuously closed.

ii) for every converging sequence $\{x_n\} \subset A$ the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n = x$ is in $A$.

This is equivalent to i)

If we use def i) and claim $A$ is closed and we take a convergent sequence $\{\x_n\}\rightarrow x$ then for any $\delta > 0$ there are an infinite $\{x_i\}$ for large enough $i$ such that $d(x_i, x) < \delta$.  Either this $x_i$ are all equal to $x$ and $\{x_n\}$ becomes a constant sequence in which case $x = x_i \in A$, or the $x_i \ne x$ and as $d(x_i, x) < \delta$, $x_i \in N_{\delta}(x)$ so $x$ is a limit point therefore in $A$.  So in either case $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n = x \in A$.  So  def i $\implies$ def ii.

If we use def ii) and claim $A$ is closed and if $x$ is a limit point of $A$: For each $n \in \mathbb N$ $1/n > 0$ and we can find an $x_n \in N_{1/n}(x); x_n \in A; x_n \ne x$.  Then $\{x_n\}\rightarrow x$ is a convergent sequence in $A$.  So $x \in A$.  So def ii $\implies$ def i.

Def iii)  $A$ is closed, if the compliment of $A$ is open.

Open means for every point $x \in A$ there is a real $\delta > 0$ so that $N_{\delta}(x) \subseteq A$.

Def iii) is equivalent to def) i.

Let $x \in X$ (unknown whether $x \in A$ or not) but a limit point of $A$.  As every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$, The neighborhood is not a subset of the complement of $A$.  So if the compliment of $A$ is open then all limit points are in $A$.

If no limit points are in the compliment of $A$, then no point of $A$ compliment is a limit point of $A$ so for every point in the compliment of $A$ there is some neighborhood with no point of $A$.  So the compliment of $A$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

The definition should be that $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed if it contains the limit of any *convergent* sequence $(x_n)$, with $x_n \in A$ for all $n$. A way to show this in your case is to make a counter assumption:

Let $x_n \to x$ with $x_n\in A$ for all $n$ and $x \not\in A$.

A contradiction is obtained in a few lines.

Comment: Contradiction in this case will be obtained from the definition of this specific A, that is  $x$ will be greater or equal to $0$ hence also an element of A?

Comment: Yes. You will have that $x \geq 0$, which is $x \in A$ which contradicts $x \not\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

The most general definition of closed set is the following: $A$ is closed (in $\mathbb{R}$) if $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is open.

Now, in your case $\mathbb{R} \setminus A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x<0 \}$. Pick any $p <0$, and let $\delta = -p>0$. The interval $(p-\delta/2,p+\delta/2)$ contains $p$ and is contained in $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$. Hence the complement of $A$ is an open set.